# Intersection operation on set

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I have two sets in a list which is followed,

```
set_list= [{224, 3, 138, 17, 222, 223}, {226, 3, 46, 17, 222, 223}]
```

I want to apply intersection operation on this list and the output should be like this:

```
set_list= [3,17,222,223]
```

Comment: Use `set.intersection(*set_list)`. FYI I had to google for "intersection of multiple sets in python" to find the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result  = set.intersection(*set_list)
```